# Show an image thats hidden thats on a view controller from another view controller that has a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I have two squares on one `ViewController` which are `ImageView`s.  One is white the other black.  At any time one is hidden, the other is one shown.  I want to switch which one is shown based on if the user presses a `Button` that's either white or black and is on another `ViewController`. I want to show this when I press on a `Button` to go back to the first `ViewController` and either the black square is showing or white square is showing depending on which `Button` I selected from a `Button` that's on another `ViewController`.

Comment: I am using storyboards not xibs in Xcode

Comment: Nope, not clear at all. The minimum would be that you give us a few screenshots of what you're looking for. And you're supposed to show us what you've done and ask questions about the specific problems you're encountering.

Comment: Thats exactly my problem I want to show image thats on a view  controller from another view controller that has a button.

Comment: Why do you have multiple view controllers?

Comment: can you show your code for that feature?

Comment: Im building a game that you pick a character from a button which is on one view controller and it shows the image on the next. I dont have code for the feature but im trying to find out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the state of the ImageViews (on or off) in NSUserDefaults or a Singleton from the first controller when pressing the associated button.  Then grab this state from the second view controller so you know what to display.